# Exported metrics not updated on webpage

Tags: java, prometheus

I am very new on Prometheus.

I am reading metric values from files and would like to display them using the Prometheus JAVA client.
After I have registered the values in Prometheus they are also exported as HTML page.

**My problem:**
If the values in the read files change, the web page doesn't show the new values. What is going wrong here?

```
HTTPServer server = new HTTPServer.Builder()
            .withPort(8080)
            .build();

while (true) {
   readFiles();
   registerPromValues();
   Thread.sleep(1000*60*5); 
   //* Update with new Value;
   gauge.set(Double.valueOf(result));
   
}
```

Please help me

Thanks
Alejandro

Comment: "
I don't use micrometer. I use the example on github.com/prometheus/client_java. I get the metrics on localhost:8080 but in second run, when metrics changed, the website shows the old values."

Comment: Do you wait at least 5 minutes and 15 seconds for the metrics to change in the HTTP response?

Comment: I had such a problem when I wanted to cover many metrics with a variable. It didn't quite work and changed values were not updated on the website.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. I created a minimal example that continually changes the value of a gauge and then sleeps for 30 seconds each time in a loop, and it works fine; I can see the values changing. Please edit your question by showing a self-contained minimal executable that shows the problem.